# Plugged tire, should I patch it if it holds air or I'm ok?

Tags: tires

Found a small screw in my rear winter tire, like real small and thought it wouldn't leak, but it did, so I plugged it. It holds air correctly.

Two questions:

- Some people freak about plugging/patching tires near the shoulder or outside the last "water" tread. Mine is close to that (about 1" from the sidewall), but also 1/2" from that last water tread. Am I OK? I had no trouble plugging it, and I think that if the small screw would have hit the shoulder, since it's the thickest part, it would haven't leak air.
- Can I keep it like that or I absolutely need a patch at the shop? Tire was never flat even with the screw, so no internal tire damage.

Tires are Run flats with plenty of good treads (which is why I don't feel like just trashing it). Winter tires, no high speed stuff, daily driver.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me; I would not be concerned as long as the tire holds pressure

Comment: UPDATE: The plug is going strong and survived Canadian winter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me for the following reasons:

- the size and shape of the hole can be fixed by a tire plug
- you plugged it and it is holding pressure
- the plug is in a flat portion of the tire profile, well away from the shoulder
- if done properly, plugs can often outlast the useful life of the tire (so longevity isn't a concern)

You would consider applying a patch from the inside if the shape of the puncture is odd or unsuitable for a tire plug (more like a tear than a hole)

Comment: Some people say that inside patch if the permanent solution, but lots of people on the Internet say that they used plug for the lifetime of their tire so kind of puzzled here. I think I'll keep an eye on the PSI and leave it like that if it works.

Comment: @allaire I wouldn't lose sleep over it. I've had plenty of tires plugged on several different cars. It's deceptively reliable

Comment: Also when installing the plug, it didn't come out that much (I didn't have to cut any excess, just like the picture is showing). No leak. I suppose I'm good?

Comment: @Allaire - I've probably done in excess of a 100 plugs over the years. I've *never* had a problem with them losing air. As Zaid said, they are deceptively reliable. I've even used two plugs in a larger hole and had that work out just fine. The stupid little things just work and work well. They truly are *fire and forget*.

Answer (score 4):

The Tire Industry Association is the keeper of standards for tires. These are the methods and standards tire manufactures want us to use.

Holes inside the area shown are allowed to be patched, outside of this the tire is to be replaced.

[image: Tire patch area]

The state of the art for a hole is too install a plug patch from the inside of the tire.

[image: Tire plug patch]

Technicians will perform other repairs such as string plugs installed from the outside and patches installed on sidewalls, these types of repairs are not recommended by tire manufactures.

This page has a more thorough discussion of the tire repair standards. https://www.tireindustry.org/tire-maintenance/tire-repair

Comment: The first diagram is a bit extreme, this one is exactly my tire and it seems that I'm sitting a couple mm on the yellow side: http://www.hometyre.co.uk/assets/Puncture_image.jpg

Comment: @allaire  Standards do vary, I have to operate on the US standards so those are the ones I know. The UK has been a leader in tire standards, so I will not try to argue with them. The concern is that the inner patch should be able to remain flat and not have to bend into a compound curve which could cuase it to peel off.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you think the inner patch will touch the curve based on where my plug is on the picture? I have no idea how big a pitch is inside the tire, but my screw is about 1" from the shoulder-to-sidewall area. If I have a plug+patch and the patch peel off, will it throws my balance off?

Comment: @allaire  It depends on wound path and tire construction. If the puncture is angled in toward the center and the inner corner radius is small it might just work. Since the tire has to come off the wheel to install this patch tire balancing is needed in any case and tires that have been worn will no longer be in balance.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred. One last question, what happen if you push the plug and lose it in the tire?

Comment: The plug patch installed from the inside. The tire is removed from the wheel and then the stem is pushed and pulled through the hole in the tire and then the excess is is trimmed off. The process is the same as for a tube patch on a bike tire. Clean the surface, apply the glue, install it and then press out any bubbles under the patch. It is not generally considered a DIY process.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the plug-patch, but I was talking about a simple plug like I installed. From what I see on the web, most of the people cut the extra cord after installation, and mine didn't come out far enough to have something to cut. No air is leaking so far, but I was wondering if my plug was still correctly installed even if i didn't come out as far as some others. Which got me thinking what happen when you push to far and the plug fall in the tire.

Comment: The type of plug you put in will work as long as the plug fills the entire wound path. The design is that the material self vulcanizes with the surrounding rubber. It should not matter if the ends hang out on the inside and they need to be cut off flush on the outside.